# how to use a variable to infer an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that is currently working:

```
type ParamType = { a: string, b: string } | { c: string }

if ('a' in params) {
  doSomethingA(params)
} else {
  doSomethingC(params)
}
```

`doSomethingA` only accepts `{ a: string, b: string }` while `doSomethingC` only accepts `{ c: string }`

The issue I'm running into is I recently changed a key in `{ a: string, b: string }` and typescript didn't complain on the `'a' in params` as I would have liked. So I made the following update:

```
type A = { a: string, d: string }
type B = { c: string }
type ParamType = A | B

const testKey: keyof A = 'd'

if (testKey in params) {
  doSomethingA(params)
} else {
  doSomethingC(params)
}
```

however now typescript does not infer the type of `params` correctly within the if/else and I get:

```
Property 'd' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.

Is there a way to ensure that the key I'm using in my if statement is one of the keys from A while also getting correct types within the if statement itself?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think TypeScript doesn't have that functionality (yet?). As you seen `if ('d' in params) {` works to narrow down the types in if branches, but even `const testKey = 'd'; if (testKey in params) {` doesn't work despite the fact that `testKey` is precisely the same type as `'d'` in that case.

You can create custom type guard function that checks the keys but you will have to implement it and repeat in the implementation the keys you defined for type because types don't follow into runtime code

```
type A = { a: string, d: string }
type B = { c: string }
type ParamType = A | B

function isA(ob:A|B, key:keyof A | keyof B): ob is A {
    return new Set(['a', 'd']).has(key);
}

const g = (params:ParamType) =>  {
    const testKey:keyof A = 'a'

    if (isA(params, testKey)) {
        doSomethingD(params)
    } else {
        doSomethingC(params)
    }
}
```